# (python)is generating and executing code at runtime considered bad practice?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and i want to learn good practices from the start i had a problem and i came up with a solution that involved generating variables on runtime, this is a sample of what i was doing

```
for i in range (10):
    current = 'variable'+str(i)+' = '+str(i)
    exec (current)
```

So, is doing things like this considered bad practice i know this is a simple example but i can see this getting complicated if you include objects in the mix, i'm bad at determine good readable code from bad one(i'm a newbie after all) so i'm asking you vets if this is frowned upon what are the prefered ways to handle situations like this.

Comment: Short answer: yes, that's *definitely* bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

No, this isn't a good practice. Whatever you're doing, the solution is probably to put your data in a dict, then you can just access mydict['variable1'] or whatever.

There ARE times when exec is reasonable, but they are typically cases of advanced metaprogramming.

A guideline here: If you don't know exactly why your're doing it, and why there is no other way, don't.

Answer (score 4):

I'm hardly a vet, but the problem I see with this are:

- Readability, as you mention. It's also difficult to debug because the buggy code might be assembled from all over the place.
- Syntax errors at runtime. This is even more annoying, in my experience, than logical errors.
- Code injection, and this one's the killer. How do you make sure that `current` does not code you do not want executed? (This web applications: a remote user might try to erase your data.) In practice, you have to make that very very sure that current does not include anything that comes from user input that it's usually faster and safer to find a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to handle several related quantities is to put them in an appropriate sort of container. That applies no matter what language you're using.

In Python, the normal containers are lists, tuples and dicts. You choose depending on what you're going to be doing with the contents.

Further, you can create a new list of any sort of "patterned" or "transformed" data easily with a list comprehension:

```
number_strings = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
# number_strings is a list of 10 values, each of which is a string
# representation of the numbers 0 through 9 inclusive. range(10) creates a
# list of 10 values, being the integers 0 through 9; we then process that 
# list with the list comprehension, transforming each integer with 'str'.
```

Comment: What he did was just `number_strings = range(10)` - think about what the str(i) does in exec.